# JAX-RS HTTP multipart request

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, multipartform-data, multipart

How to implement *multipart/form-data* request (file upload) handler with JAX-RS without vendor specific libraries? So far I haven't found other way than to inject the `HttpServletRequest` and use the Servlet API to access the form data.

Yet `HttpServletRequest#getParts()` returns an empty list even the request is well formed (confirmed with Wireshark). I read I have to enable multipart configuration for the Jersey Servlet in the web.xml. However, I'm using `@ApplicationPath` annotation to automatically configure JAX-RS. So what is the correct way to handle multipart requests?

Answer (score 2):

This code may inspire you

**1) JAXRS App setup**

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;


@ApplicationPath("demo") 
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
   public ApplicationConfig() {
     packages("com.mycompany.demo").register(MultiPartFeature.class); // <= here!
   }
}
```

**2) JAXRS service**

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImage(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream data,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileInfo) {
...
}
```